# Jackson: custom deserializer on an interface

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an `interface Thing`, implemented by `class ThingImpl`. I have a custom Jackson serializer and deserializer registered for the interface, `Thing`. All works great on serialization, and when deserializing when Jackson is told the type: `mapper.readValue(json, Thing.class)`.

But, I have cases where Jackson needs to deserialize a `Thing` when the type is not statically known - like as the value in a `Map<String, Object>`. To support that, I added an annotation to `Thing` to tell it to add type info:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CLASS)
```

...and I updated the serializer to write out the type info by overriding `serializeWithType`.

Now, the `@class` attribute is added to the serialized form and when deserializing, Jackson recognizes the type info - but the class name written to `@class` is the implementation, `ThingImpl`, rather than the interface, and it doesn't invoke my custom deserializer for the interface, `Thing`. Instead, it tries to naively deserialize to a `ThingImpl` and fails.

How can I tell Jackson to use my `Thing` deserializer for `ThingImpl`s, or tag serialized `ThingImpl`s as `Thing`s?

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to avoid annotating the classes (mostly for not-very-convincing aesthetic reasons), but adding `@JsonDeserialize(using = ThingDeserializer.class)` to `ThingImpl` does the trick.